# Kendo ui Grid export to Excel and CSV using javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, csv, kendo-ui

please help me my probs,am using kendo ui grid in my webapp & trying to grid data export into EXcel and CSV format. Code Works good in Chrome and files are downloading, but in Fire Fox its open a new window show the grid details in url and says bad request,

//code is

```
$("#exportcsv").click(function (e) {
           debugger
           var dataSource = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;

           var filteredDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
               data: dataSource.data(),
               filter: dataSource.filter()
           });

           filteredDataSource.read();
           var data = filteredDataSource.view();

           //start with the desired column headers here
           var result = "\"ID\",\"EID\",\"Name\",\"Company Name\",\"Salary\",\"DID\",\"Date Of Join\"";

           //each column will need to be called using the field name in the data source
           for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
               result += "\n";

               result += "\"" + data[i].id + "\",";

               result += "\"" + data[i].EID + "\",";

               result += "\"" + data[i].EName + "\",";

               result += "\"" + data[i].CName + "\",";

               result += "\"" + data[i].Salary + "\",";

               result += "\"" + data[i].DID + "\",";

               result += "\"" + data[i].DOJ + "\",";
           }





           if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
               //Internet Explorer
               window.navigator.msSaveBlob(new Blob([result]), 'ExportedKendoGrid.csv');
           }

           else if (window.webkitURL != null) {

                   //Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox
                   var a = document.createElement('a');
                   result = encodeURIComponent(result);
                   a.href = 'data:application/csv;charset=UTF-8,' + result;
                   a.download = 'ExportedKendoGrid.csv';
                   a.click();
               }
           else {
               //Everything Else
               window.open(result);
           }
           e.preventDefault();
       });
```

> //not executing in firefox this code   else if (window.webkitURL !=
>   null) {
>
> ```
>                    //Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox
>                    var a = document.createElement('a');
>                    result = encodeURIComponent(result);
>                    a.href = 'data:application/csv;charset=UTF-8,' + result;
>                    a.download = 'ExportedKendoGrid.csv';
>                    a.click();
>                }
> ```

Comment: Just making sure here, but you do know the latest version of KendoUI has excel (and pdf) exporting built in ?  http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/excel-export

Comment: And FYI this will not work in IE

Comment: thanks @RobinGiltner for your rply, am using latest version of kendo ui,hence i used first excel and pdf built in but i didn't get, am confusing about proxy url, if u have a example please make me help. When am tried to fail get using kendo ui excel built in, i preferred above code please help me and give solution better one Thank you